# Tendermint Consensus - Resilient up to 1/3 of Byzantine participants

Tags: distributed-systems

Tendermint Consensus is resilient for up to 1/3 of Byzantine participants.

Question: What actually happens after when the network hits the threshold of byzantine actors? Forking happens? Does transaction fails for honest nodes?

Similarly, for all the BFT/PBFT consensus algorithm, what happens after when the network hits the threshold for Byzantine actors?